# Can't set scheduled local notifications: Unknown property: trigger

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, localnotification

In package.json I have following:

```
"@ionic-native/local-notifications": "^5.15.1",
"cordova-plugin-local-notification": "^0.9.0-beta.3",
```

When I use 'trigger' property:

```
this.localNotifications.schedule({
   title: 'In 15 seconds',
   //foreground: true,
   trigger: { in: 15, unit: ELocalNotificationTriggerUnit.SECOND }
})
```

I'm getting error in the console:

```
"Unknown property: trigger"
```

Any ideas?

Comment: did you tried scheduling like this - `cordova.plugins['notification'].local.schedule({
      text: 'Test notifucation',
      trigger: {in: 15, unit: 'second'},
    });`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was using Ionic DevApp, but it doesn't support local notifications

Comment: After taking the build and installed on real device, where you able to get it right?

Comment: I had the same problem last night. After building on an emulator the notifications worked as expected. Seems like they just don't work on DevApp.